# Incorrect date conversion by SimpleDateFormat

Tags: android

I am using SimpleDateFormat to convert the date from dd-MM-yyyy to yyyy-MM-dd
 but I does not display the year properly.I am trying to convert 18-5-2014 to 2014-05-18 
 but I am getting 3914-05-18.

```
 public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
 {

  Date selectedDate = new Date(year,monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

  String strDate = null;

      SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

      strDate = dateFormatter.format(selectedDate);

      txtdeliverydate.setText(strDate);

  }
```

Comment: what is the value in `selectedDate` ???

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you didn't read the documentation for the [(deprecated) `Date` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date-int-int-int-) you're using:

> **Parameters:**
>   year - the year minus 1900.
>   month - the month between 0-11.
>   date - the day of the month between 1-31.

Avoid using `Date` here. Either use a *good* date/time library like Joda Time, or use `Calendar` to set year/month/day values - even then, the month will be 0-based.

Also, your method is currently *accepting* year/month/day values... if you're actually just trying to do a conversion, you should be accepting a string and returning a string, e.g.

```
public static String convertDateFormat(String text) {
    TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC");
    SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);
    parser.setTimeZone(utc);
    Date date = parser.parse(text);

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
    formatter.setTimeZone(utc);
    return formatter.format(date);
}
```

Comment: Great answer Jon